# How to build qt out of source

Tags: qt, installation, qmake

I was searching a lot through Qt forums and Google for the last few days, but I could not find any obvious answer to this question.

I found the `-prefix` option (not even documented on Windows) that can be supplied to configure to specify different install directory, but this is not clear separation of the sources and binaries at all, since the build is still done in the source directory and then the files needed for installation are copied to the install directoy. I tried this `-prefix` option, and came to some problems. (i.e It doesn't  copy the `.pdb` files to the install directory.)

Then I found [this link](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/shadow-builds-wince.html) about doing shadow builds but it has the big limitation that the build dir must be at the same level as the source dir.

---

> I'm guessing you didn't try make
>   install? So try that. It should
>   install Qt to a separate directory
>   away from the sources.

Are you saying that after I do configure, I should do nmake install instead just nmake? I know that nmake will process the generated makefiles from qmake and will place them in the source Qt dir, but what nmake install will exactly do i.e in which directory will install the files and how to specify the directory where the files will be installed.

Note that I already do this:

```
configure -prefix builddir -platform win32-msvc2005
nmake install
```

The effect of the above two lines was that qt was compiled in the source dir and not directly to my builddir specified with prefix. Then the compiled files were copied in my builddir. I was hoping for something that will build my Qt files directly to the build dir, cause this way I  stil need 4 Gb space for my source dir during the compilation. Also the pdb files were not copied to my buildir which is another issue.

Comment: Is it possible to build using cmake?

Comment: This describes an out-of-source build for Qt: http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/#comment-6641

Answer (score 15):

Basically, you just have to run configure.exe from your build directory.  For example:

```
mkdir \qt\4.5.2-build
cd \qt\4.5.2-build
set PATH=%cd%\bin;%PATH%
\qt\4.5.2-sources\configure.exe -platform win32-msvc2005
```

Where sources are in `\qt\4.5.2-sources`, that would cause the build to go into `\qt\4.5.2-build` on the current drive.

Also, you must have perl in your `PATH`, ActiveState Perl is suggested.

I had not previously heard of this limitation where the build and source directories must be at the same level.  If you hit this problem you could try working around it by creating a symbolic link (see `mklink` command).

Comment: This does not work.
The error says  that it can't include some .h file

Comment: the error is at configure time and it says that it can't include some qscriptengine.h. Also in my try the build directory was not in the same level as the source directory (like in your primer above). Is this relevant?

Comment: It sounds like the syncqt script wasn't run.  This script generates headers in the build tree pointing back to the source tree.

One reason why it mightn't run is if you don't have perl installed and in PATH.  I added a comment about perl to my answer.

Comment: Here is my folder structure :

--X
  --qt
  --shadow

I want to build in shadow :
cd C:/X/shadow
C:/X/qt/configure.exe -platform win32-msvc2005421904

I also have shadow/bin and path to perl.exe in my PATH.

And Iam still getting the same error at configure time :

c:\x\qt\qmake\project.h(57) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qscriptengine.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Also note that I am getting the error when configure tries to build qmake.

Comment: I can't believe  that there is no support from qmake (or maybe am missing something) to do this i.e to build out of source. It is such a common requirement. How suppose to store my qt library on repository now ? ha

Comment: qmake (and configure, and Qt) does support this, I and many others do it all the time.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it step by step please. I tried everything I can think of so far.  Thank you

Comment: ActivePerl is a must for out-of-tree builds, not a suggestion. @user152508, you are gettings this error because configure script fails to copy header files. I suspect you don't have ActivePerl's `perl` in your $PATH.

Comment: I have the same problem as @user152508, and I definitely have ActivePerl in my %PATH%. It just doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem too. I have ActivePerl in my path; I get numerous include files not found errors. The perl script is not properly changing the paths, but added an additional "..\..\" to every header file path in the build files.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC on Windows, you have to do a sandbox install, you can't do the UNIX-typical "make install".

There are two options usually for building Qt, -prefix-install and -prefix /foo

You pick one, so if -prefix doesn't allow you to type make install, then I guess on Windows you have to use the -prefix-install route, which is a sandboxed install to the directory you extract Qt to.

I'm guessing you didn't try make install? So try that. It should install Qt to a separate directory away from the sources.

Comment: Which program `-prefix-install` and `-prefix /path` are options for? They are not mentioned in the output of `configure.exe --help`

Comment: I wrote that answer 16 months ago. It may be that the Qt configure has changed.

Answer (score 0):

At least the problem with the missing include files (e.g. qscriptengine.h) may by solved by temporary adding \qt\4.5.2-sources\include\Qt to the include path.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the shadow build out of my home folder to a folder in C: and it worked. I know it's weird, but that's what happened. I suspect it must be a bug in syncqt.