# Installing QT Visual Studio Addin

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I'm trying to follow this guide to install the QT plugin into VS 2010: http://thomasstockx.blogspot.ca/2011/03/qt-472-in-visual-studio-2010.html

After when I reach Step 11 and try to execute the command:

```
configure -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -no-qt3support -qt-sql-sqlite -phonon -phonon-backend -no-webkit -no-script -platform win32-msvc2010
```

I get the following error:

```
'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm using the VS command prompt window and not a regular command prompt window. Can someone one please suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Currently, I see the add-in in VS . However, when I click Qt-> Launch Designer, I get this error message:

```
No default QT version found. Please check your QT Visual Studio Add-in settings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`configure.exe` is a executable file in the root of Qt source tree(as QTDIR). Before you try to execute this command, make sure your working path is the QTDIR. If you work out off QTDIR, give the right prefix path to command `configure`. This is shadow build, perl is required.

Comment: Thanks Liuyi. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "shadow" build?

Comment: Shadow building means building a project in a separate directory, the build directory. The build directory is different from the source directory. One of the benefits of shadow building is that it keeps your source directory clean. Shadow building is the best practice if you need many build configurations for a single set of source.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245011/how-to-build-qt-out-of-source