# Installing Qt with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, build

I have followed the directions [here](http://thomasstockx.blogspot.com/2011/03/qt-472-in-visual-studio-2010.html) to download and extract the files for Qt and prepare my VS environment for installation.

However, when I run the configure command listed there in a VS2010 command prompt, it says 'configure is not recognized as an internal or external command'.

Is there something wrong with my path or something? Where do I find the configure utility file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What directory are you in when you run the configure command? There should be a configure.exe in your Qt installation directory.

Comment: @Chris I'm in the folder I extracted the source to.. "C:\Qt\4.7.4\" but there is no configure.exe that I see. Is it buried somewhere in the folder structure?

Comment: It should also be noted that the article you're reading is out of date. Qt now ships a precompiled version for VS2010 : http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2010

Comment: @Chris .....well then. I think I will try that one. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Jgord configure.exe is in the top level QT dir - if it's not you have a broken download

Comment: Please reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660346/installing-qt-visual-studio-addin/11661186#11661186